# basic auth apache & symfony

Tags: symfony, authentication, redirect, basic-authentication

We are hosting a symfony website, but we would like to restrict the access to it for a few users untill it is ready to be launched publicly .
we would like to use basic authentication to "protect" the webpage in the meanwhile.

when i don't set up basic auth on our vhost the webpage works fine
but if i set this up

```
       <Directory /path/web>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Content"
        AuthUserFile /path/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
      <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
         Options -MultiViews
         RewriteEngine On
         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
         RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]
      </IfModule>
   </Directory>
```

we get the error in symfony that there were too many redirects . 
is there a way to allow symfony to work properly using this setup?

Comment: Whats the symfony errors?

Comment: no symfony error at all , just a default message , ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: See if this helps: http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/jz87/how-to-create-a-user-login-screen-with-htaccess-and-htpasswd-to-prevent-users-to-access-subfolders-or-resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dev team apparantly used security features from symfony aswell , the user had to be added in the user table of symfony to work.